# AWS Dynamo table writing data incorrectly for some records

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have written a script that calls a lambda function on AWS this lambda is supposed to write records to a Dynamo table.

The correct format that most of the time gets written is:

`"yearOfBirth": "1973/01/01",
  "yearsOfExperience": "5 or more years",
  "zipCode": "60657"`

There are a few that get written like this:

`"yearOfBirth": {
    "S": "1973/01/01"
  },
  "yearsOfExperience": {
    "S": "5 or more years"
  },
  "zipCode": {
    "S": "60657"
  }`

What causes this?

Edit:

Code that I am using which I pass onto `docClient.put()`

```
var profile = require('../model/userProfile.js');
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports.save = function(userId, data, tableName, cb) {
  _(data).forIn(function(value, key) {
    var keyAttr = key;
    var valAttr = value;

    var params = {
      TableName: tableName,
      Key: {
        id: userId
      },
      UpdateExpression: 'SET #attrName = :attrValue',
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#attrName': keyAttr
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':attrValue': valAttr
      }
    };

    profile.appendDataToUser(params, cb);
  });
};
```

profile.appendDataToUser just does a call to `docClient.put()`

Comment: We need the code of your lambda function

Answer (score 0):

A sample code will be useful. But, I suspecting you might be using `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` to write your records and specifying fields types at the same time. If you are using `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` you don't need to specify fields types, you can just pass a plain javascript object. But if you are using `AWS.DynamoDB` you need to specify fields types.

Using `AWS.DynamoDB`

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

dynamodb.putItem({
    TableName: 'user',
    Item: {
        "yearOfBirth": {
            "S": "1973/01/01"
        },
        "yearsOfExperience": {
            "S": "5 or more years"
        },
        "zipCode": {
            "S": "60657"
        }
    }
});
```

Using `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`

```
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

dynamodb.put({
    TableName: 'user',
    Item: {
        "yearOfBirth": "1973/01/01",
        "yearsOfExperience": "5 or more years",
        "zipCode": "60657"
    }
});
```

Comment: That is correct I am using `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()`

Comment: Also using `docClient.put()' I will edit original post to include the code that I am using on the lambda.